Include log4j2.xml in classes directory, IntellIJ
im currently trying to switch to IntelliJ but ive ran into a little problem:
My log4j2.xml is located in my src directory /src and has to be copied into the classes directory, sadly it has to stay that way. If i now try to run the app the log4j2.xml is not copied to out/production/classes directory like it should be. I already tried to configure the compiler Resource pattern but I cant get it work with that either. Is there any other way to get what i want?
Is:
/
   src/
      log4j2.xml
      ... (.java files)
   out/
      ... (.class files)
Need:
/
   src/
      log4j2.xml
      ... (.java files)
   out/
      log4j2.xml
      ... (.class files)

Thanks in advance!

Is it copied on "Build | Build Project" action? Is it reproducible with new sample project? It seems to be working fine on my side.
